# Reshaping after numpy loadtxt: cannot reshape array of size x into shape (x,y)

Tags: python, file, numpy

I have the following text file, file.txt with 3 rows and 4 columns:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 10.0
15 10 2001 2995
```

I'm using np.loadtxt to read it in as an array. Loadtxt reads it in as a 1-D array and I'd like to convert it back to the 3x4 array it's structured as in the text file. I've tried

```
file = sys.argv[1] #I'm just reading it from the command line when executing the program
data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t', dtype = str)
print(data.shape, data)
data = data.reshape(3,4)
```

but receive the following error:

```
(3,)
['0.0 0.0 0.0' '0.0 0.0 10.0' '15 10 2001 2995']
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3,4)
```

I've edited out the non-pertinent information between the shape and the error. How can I reshape this text file back to a 3x4 array? It doesn't have to be through load text. I've also tried using np.genfromtxt as well to no avail.

Comment: Why are you using `delimiter=','` for a file not delimited by `,`?

Comment: And why do you assert that the input structure is 3x4?

Comment: Fixed the delimiter. That's what It looked like when I opened the file in a text editor.

Comment: In a `copy-n-paste the tabs, if any, don't pass through.  So your sample just looks like 'white-space' delimited.  The first 2 lines have 3 columns, but the last has 4.  Hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `reshape` the data, just change the delimiter in the `loadtxt` function from `,` to space `' '`:

```
data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=' ', dtype = str)
```

This will actually load your data as 3x4 array of strings with missing element appearing as an empty string `''`. You can then replace it with zeros using

```
np.place(data, data == '', '0.0')
```

And convert to floats using:

```
data = np.asarray(data, dtype = float)
```

Comment: Not an error, unfortunately. Those are just whitespaces i suppose. The text file I was given had no values there. I'm not sure how to actually add those in correctly in my example.

Comment: So how does your data look like? I mean when I ran your code as it is in the OP it gave me a reshaping error because the input array was a 3 element array with each element being a row of your sample input.

Comment: Yes, this must be the problem. I apologize, I'm somewhat new at this. Was looking to get that text into a numpy array with shape 3,4.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is great at reading data with missing entries. If you don't have pandas, you may install it with:

```
pip install pandas
```

After this, you could do use `pd.read_table` to read your data. Missing values are replaced with `NaN`s.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_table('data.txt', sep='\s+', 
            header=None, names=range(4)).values

print(x)
array([[    0.,     0.,     0.,    nan],
       [    0.,     0.,    10.,    nan],
       [   15.,    10.,  2001.,  2995.]])
```